# My tab content (and slider) is not displaying when I upload my website via FTP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

When I edit my HTML5 +css site offline, tab content (and slider image) displays perfectly however as soon as I upload the site none of the content of my tabs appear and my slider image disappears. I have tried uploading in ascii and also tried uploading a page containing an unedited tab section (from the original template) to see if I had made a mistake but the same happens.

As a relative novice I am stuck at this point.

Offline my site appears like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/6uw907q005h39lv/site.jpg

But here is the link to the uploaded page: http://cardiffsme.co.uk/IELTS%206.0.html

It is no different in firefox, chrome or the latest IE.

If anyone can suggest some possible reason I would be very grateful. I have tried replacing my CSS folder with the original - no change. My Head contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie ie9 no-js" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Cardiff School of Modern English</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_color1/olive.css" id="main-color1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_color2/red.css" id="main-color2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main_bg/green.css" id="main-bg-scheme">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300|Open+Sans:400,700,300,600,400italic,600italic|Ubuntu:400italic">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/switcher.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
    background-color: #f8f9f4;
}
    </style> 
    <!-- Style Switcher -->

    <!-- Java Script -->
    <script>document.documentElement.className = document.documentElement.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/g, 'js');</script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->

</head>
```

I have moved and copied the website a few times between computers. I don't know if that could have affected the links.. With firebug I have the following errors (a long list!):

```
Image corrupt or truncated: http://cardiffsme.co.uk/images/portfolio/img3-380x238.jpg
2
SyntaxError: missing : after property id


sibility:"hidden",display:"block"},Kt={letterSpacing:0,fontW


jquery.min.js (line 6, col 60)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...paq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le...

detect...wser.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;

jquery....min.js (line 38)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...] iframe[src*='www.kickstarter.com'] object embed".split(" ");c.customSelector&&...

jquery....min.js (line 13)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23"...

jquery....min.js (line 11)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...;c.controlNav&&f.controlNav.active(); k||a.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide")....

jquery....min.js (line 14)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...is.settings.events.start&&this.settings.events.start(p),h?(b=c?"ease-out":"ease-...

jquery....min.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...ash()[0];a.tweet_text_fancy=c([a.tweet_text]).makeHeart()[0];a.user=f('<a class=...

jquery....min.js (line 29)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

custom.js (line 4)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

switcher.js (line 7)
Image corrupt or truncated: http://cardiffsme.co.uk/images/feature3-420x236.jpg
SyntaxError: missing : after property id


sibility:"hidden",display:"block"},Kt={letterSpacing:0,fontW


jquery.min.js (line 6, col 60)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...paq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le...

detect...wser.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;

jquery....min.js (line 38)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...] iframe[src*='www.kickstarter.com'] object embed".split(" ");c.customSelector&&...

jquery....min.js (line 13)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23"...

jquery....min.js (line 11)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...;c.controlNav&&f.controlNav.active(); k||a.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide")....

jquery....min.js (line 14)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...is.settings.events.start&&this.settings.events.start(p),h?(b=c?"ease-out":"ease-...

jquery....min.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...ash()[0];a.tweet_text_fancy=c([a.tweet_text]).makeHeart()[0];a.user=f('<a class=...

jquery....min.js (line 29)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

custom.js (line 4)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

switcher.js (line 7)
Warning: Enabling the Script panel causes a Firefox slow-down due to a platform bug. This will be fixed with the next major Firefox and Firebug versions.
Warning: Enabling the Script panel causes a Firefox slow-down due to a platform bug. This will be fixed with the next major Firefox and Firebug versions.
Image corrupt or truncated: http://cardiffsme.co.uk/images/feature3-420x236.jpg
Warning: Enabling the Script panel causes a Firefox slow-down due to a platform bug. This will be fixed with the next major Firefox and Firebug versions.
SyntaxError: missing : after property id


sibility:"hidden",display:"block"},Kt={letterSpacing:0,fontW


switcher.js (line 7, col 60)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...paq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le...

detect...wser.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;

jquery....min.js (line 38)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...] iframe[src*='www.kickstarter.com'] object embed".split(" ");c.customSelector&&...

jquery....min.js (line 13)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23"...

jquery....min.js (line 11)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...;c.controlNav&&f.controlNav.active(); k||a.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide")....

jquery....min.js (line 14)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...is.settings.events.start&&this.settings.events.start(p),h?(b=c?"ease-out":"ease-...

jquery....min.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...ash()[0];a.tweet_text_fancy=c([a.tweet_text]).makeHeart()[0];a.user=f('<a class=...

jquery....min.js (line 29)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

custom.js (line 4)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

switcher.js (line 7)
Warning: Enabling the Script panel causes a Firefox slow-down due to a platform bug. This will be fixed with the next major Firefox and Firebug versions.
SyntaxError: missing : after property id


sibility:"hidden",display:"block"},Kt={letterSpacing:0,fontW


switcher.js (line 7, col 60)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...paq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le...

detect...wser.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;

jquery....min.js (line 38)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...] iframe[src*='www.kickstarter.com'] object embed".split(" ");c.customSelector&&...

jquery....min.js (line 13)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23"...

jquery....min.js (line 11)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...;c.controlNav&&f.controlNav.active(); k||a.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide")....

jquery....min.js (line 14)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...is.settings.events.start&&this.settings.events.start(p),h?(b=c?"ease-out":"ease-...

jquery....min.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...ash()[0];a.tweet_text_fancy=c([a.tweet_text]).makeHeart()[0];a.user=f('<a class=...

jquery....min.js (line 29)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

custom.js (line 4)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

switcher.js (line 7)
Warning: Enabling the Script panel causes a Firefox slow-down due to a platform bug. This will be fixed with the next major Firefox and Firebug versions.
SyntaxError: missing : after property id


sibility:"hidden",display:"block"},Kt={letterSpacing:0,fontW


switcher.js (line 7, col 60)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...paq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le...

detect...wser.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;

jquery....min.js (line 38)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...] iframe[src*='www.kickstarter.com'] object embed".split(" ");c.customSelector&&...

jquery....min.js (line 13)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23"...

jquery....min.js (line 11)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...;c.controlNav&&f.controlNav.active(); k||a.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide")....

jquery....min.js (line 14)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...is.settings.events.start&&this.settings.events.start(p),h?(b=c?"ease-out":"ease-...

jquery....min.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...ash()[0];a.tweet_text_fancy=c([a.tweet_text]).makeHeart()[0];a.user=f('<a class=...

jquery....min.js (line 29)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

custom.js (line 4)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

switcher.js (line 7)
Warning: Enabling the Script panel causes a Firefox slow-down due to a platform bug. This will be fixed with the next major Firefox and Firebug versions.
SyntaxError: missing : after property id


sibility:"hidden",display:"block"},Kt={letterSpacing:0,fontW


switcher.js (line 7, col 60)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...paq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le...

detect...wser.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery.easing.jswing=jQuery.easing.swing;

jquery....min.js (line 38)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...] iframe[src*='www.kickstarter.com'] object embed".split(" ");c.customSelector&&...

jquery....min.js (line 13)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23"...

jquery....min.js (line 11)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...;c.controlNav&&f.controlNav.active(); k||a.slides.removeClass(e+"active-slide")....

jquery....min.js (line 14)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...is.settings.events.start&&this.settings.events.start(p),h?(b=c?"ease-out":"ease-...

jquery....min.js (line 8)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


...ash()[0];a.tweet_text_fancy=c([a.tweet_text]).makeHeart()[0];a.user=f('<a class=...

jquery....min.js (line 29)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

custom.js (line 4)
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

> Blockquote
```

Thank you for your time!

Andrew

Comment: it seems you don't load jQuery and you don't load the other scripts you need

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have jquery in my 'js' folder https://www.dropbox.com/s/tq9brbqi2oznkr5/js.jpg Should I add something to my header?

Comment: Have a look here : http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/.

Comment: Thank you. I think I have implemented that correctly now but still nothing. Do you have any idea why it would all display correctly when viewed in a browser from my offline folder, but not when I upload that entire folder?

Comment: your jQuery js is not well addressed on your server (and probably your other scripts)... try to put <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> in your <head> tag, and ensure this file is present in your js directory

Comment: Thank you so much for your help so far. I have re-added the script to my head and also updated my js/query.min.js to the latest version from the jquery website but still nothing has changed. What is strange is that as a test I uploaded the entire unedited template folder including js, css etc to my server and had the same problem. The tabs don't appear!